# Appodeal integration with iOS app shows error

Tags: ios, architecture, appodeal

I am trying to manually integrate Appodeal. but it show the following error. I follow [This](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=20&full=1&platform=4) documentation.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEhRi.jpg)

Can anyone help me to remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add EventKit as a framework to your project.

To do that, go to your project's settings and click on the the "Build Phases" tab.  You should see something like this:

[image: Add Frameworks Here]
Click on the "+" button to add new frameworks.

And scroll down and you should see and add "EventKit.framework".  You might also need to add "EventKitUI.framework" (it likely wouldn't hurt even if it wasn't needed).

[image: Add Event Kit framework to your project]

Comment: thanks Michael. by adding EventKit.framework it goes out 3 error. but yet it show 2 error related to

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WCSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Appodeal(ADCDevice.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Comment: Hi guys, I am facing similar issue,  did check in Build Phases everything is there, what else I can check?
Error is
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Appodeal", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libModuleAds.a(AppodealNetwork.o)

Answer (score 0):

same, in my case I had to add Appodeal.framework and GoogleMobileAds.framework in "Link with libraries"

[image]